# Trying to divide a string

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling information from my table. It is setup as a varchar. I can't change it because it 0's everything out when I do. I need to be able to divide the result by 12. It is the MY-TotalPrem that needs to be divided.

I tried

```
<td>'.$row["MS-TotalPrem" / 12].'
</td>, <td>'.$row["MS-TotalPrem"] / 12.'</td>, 
<td>'.$row[int("MS-TotalPrem") / 12].
'</td>
```

and none work.

```
function fetch_customer_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $output = '
 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Policy Number</th>
    <th>Total Monthly</th>
    <th>Expiration Date</th>
   </tr>
 ';
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["AC-AcctName"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["PM-PropertyAddr1"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["PO-Addr1"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["PO-PrefixPolNum"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["MS-TotalPrem"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["PO-ExpDate"].'</td> 
   </tr>
  ';
 }
 $output .= '
  </table>
 </div>
 ';
 return $output;
}
```

I just want the output to be a division of 12, or any other number I put in. Thank you.

Comment: #2 would be the correct syntax, though surrounding the calculation with `()` would make it a bit more readable. What is the value of `$row["MS-TotalPrem"]`?

Comment: _Small Point, probably not the issue_ There is little point preparing a query that has no parameters. You may as well just run a `->query()` on it

Comment: what about using brackets `($row["MS-TotalPrem" ] / 12)`

Comment: `$row["MS-TotalPrem"] / 12` should work fine without parens, as `/` has higher precedence than `.` What output do you actually get in that case?

Comment: something like `<td>'.($row["MS-TotalPrem"]/12).'</td>`, replace with `<td>'.$row["MS-TotalPrem"].'</td>`

Comment: <td>'.$row["MS-TotalPrem"]. / 12'</td> generates Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/'          <td>'.$row["MS-TotalPrem"] / 12.'</td> generates Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''</td>' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in

Comment: `<td>'.$row["MS-TotalPrem"] / 12.'` you dont want to divide the key (string) by 12 you want to divide the value of `$row["MS-TotalPrem"]` by 12

Comment: https://3v4l.org/G5diL

Comment: <td>'.$row(["MS-TotalPrem"] / 12.)'</td>  gets Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''</td>' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in

Comment: <td>'(.$row["MS-TotalPrem"] / 12.)'</td> gets Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in

Comment: It's not `$row(["MS-TotalPrem"] / 12.)`.. it's `<td>' . ( $row["MS-TotalPrem"] / 12 ) .  '</td>` <-- Notice where the parentheses and dots are.

Comment: so many answers in comments :)

Comment: Magnus, thank you for pointing that out. I change it to     <td>'.($row["MS-TotalPrem"]/12).'</td> and I get Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in and Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in. For some reason a lot of my numbers then become 0.

Comment: You'll need to double-check what `$row["MS-TotalPrem"]` contains. Are you sure it's always a number?

Comment: one more thing, you must need to check either `$row["MS-TotalPrem"]` greater than 0 or not, otherwise you will get more errors for division.

Comment: In the table it is a string, varchar. Yes, it is always a numeric value.

Comment: it must be numeric and greater than 0

Comment: devpro, what do you mean?

Comment: Can you show some examples of what the field contains? If you can show the field when the error occurs, that would be great.

Comment: it means, if you have 0 in `MS-TotalPrem` then it will give you error when you try to divide with 12, just like `0/12`

Comment: When I run it without division, my first four numbers are $194.58, $194.58, $194.58, $2,422.26. When I do the division, with it inside the "." I get 0,0,0,0. Could it be the $?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to strip the $ off the number first.

Comment: Yes, that was it, for the most part. I removed the $ from the table. I still get Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in when I run it, though. Not sure what that means.

Answer (score 2):

```
function fetch_customer_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $output = '
 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Policy Number</th>
    <th>Total Monthly</th>
    <th>Expiration Date</th>
   </tr>
 ';
 foreach($result as $row)
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["AC-AcctName"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["PM-PropertyAddr1"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["PO-Addr1"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["PO-PrefixPolNum"].'</td>
    <td>'.($row["MS-TotalPrem"] / 12).'</td>
    <td>'.$row["PO-ExpDate"].'</td> 
   </tr>
  ';

 $output .= '
  </table>
 </div>
 ';
 return $output;
}
```

Comment: Would you like to add some explanation of your solution and how it helps.

Comment: you can also refer question's comments in your answer for explanation

Comment: This gives me the errors Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF Create\index.php on line 35

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF Create\index.php on line 35